# Flutter: How to scroll page with onTap or onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am creating a website with Flutter Web, and I want to navigate down in the screen with onTap on top Navbar. Like we do it in web development which will navigate to a specific id.

How can I achieve this?

Can we use ScrollController?

**EDIT: I found the solution here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924800/11545939

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create links to sections in the same page in flutter web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775366/is-it-possible-to-create-links-to-sections-in-the-same-page-in-flutter-web)

Comment: Hey thanks for the source, but I am developing a responsive website so for that can I pass the controller as a variable?

Answer (score 4):

You should use **ScrollController** like this:

EDIT

```dart
var _scrollController = ScrollController();

void goUp(){
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      0.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
    );
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _scrollController,
```

Comment: I am creating a responsive website in which navbar is a different widget can I pass the scrollController within different files? And also my pages are not having full height, so can it cause some errors?

Comment: yes, you can pass **ScrollController** as parameter for each layout, no , it's okay